# Return data from mysql where value equals URI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to return a row from my database however, when I replace the `page='url'` with `$filePath = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; page='.$filePath.'` it returns nothing.

I'm assuming the answer is simple however, I can't see to find the solution.

**Full Code**

```
$filePath = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM Meta WHERE page=' . $filePath . '";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
  <title><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></title>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If you're already using mysqli, you should [bind your parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: Are you sure you have filePath in database?

Comment: @halojoy The value of filePath is in the database as I echoed it and copied and pasted the value into it,

Comment: @cteski I'm not sure i've come across this before, please demonstrate how this would work in my case?

Comment: I'm not sure your query syntax is correct. Try "SELECT * FROM Meta WHERE page='$filePath' " (without the dots in yours). But you should really use parametrised queries

Comment: @David That worked, thank you! I will look into parametrised queries now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the query like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Meta WHERE page = '" . $filePath  . "' ";
```